# decoding backtrace from compressed js

Tags: javascript, source-maps

I have some compressed js & browser-generated js backtraces (new Error("").stack converted to strings by a client and sent to my servers ): I'd like to make this backtrace more readable by converting its compressed line/column numbers to uncompressed column/line numbers.

Technically, I have access to the source code so I could try to use sourcemaps but when I have to work with a backtrace, getting back to the exact original version of the source code that generated this is not always easy.

So, I am looking for a command-line tool to beautify the compressed js *and* map the compressed line/column numbers to beautified line/column numbers. Is there an obvious solution for this ?

Comment: How is the code being compressed? Most compressors have an option to create source maps during the compression process, which you can subsequently use in your browser's dev tools.

Comment: yes, I can do that but I still need to map the compressed line/column numbers to beautified numbers and I fail to see how to do this with a browser.

Comment: Your browser will do that for you. At least Chrome will. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/readability/source-maps) for more info. Unless you want to do this from the CLI entirely?

Comment: I do not see how to make _my_ browser take as input a string that contains the stringified output of another client's new Error().stack. I have just edited my question to make it more clear

Comment: I can see how to use https://github.com/mozilla/source-map and SourceMapConsumer to do this.

Comment: Yeah I was about to point you to the same module :)